# No results when searching with dn

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-query

Thanks for reading

Here's an screenshot of my ldap
[image]
This command:

```
docker exec ldap-service ldapsearch -v -x -H ldap://localhost:389 -b dc=everteam,dc=us -D "cn=admin,dc=everteam,dc=us" -w everteam cn=estebanf
```

... return the result I'm looking for:

```
ldap_initialize( ldap://localhost:389/??base )
filter: cn=estebanf
requesting: All userApplication attributes
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=everteam,dc=us> with scope subtree
# filter: cn=estebanf
# requesting: ALL
#

# estebanf, People, everteam.us
dn: cn=estebanf,ou=People,dc=everteam,dc=us
cn: estebanf
displayName: Esteban J Felipe M
mail: e.felipe@everteam.com
givenName: Esteban Felipe
sn: Esteban Felipe
userPassword:: e01ENX00UXJjT1VtNldhdStWdUJYOGcrSVBnPT0=
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
ou: People

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1
```

But this command:

```
docker exec ldap-service ldapsearch -v -x -H ldap://localhost:389 -b dc=everteam,dc=us -D "cn=admin,dc=everteam,dc=us" -w everteam cn=estebanf,ou=People,dc=everteam,dc=us
```

.. doesn't. The difference is that I'm using the full dn

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=everteam,dc=us> with scope subtree
# filter: cn=estebanf,ou=People,dc=everteam,dc=us
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 1
ldap_initialize( ldap://localhost:389/??base )
filter: cn=estebanf,ou=People,dc=everteam,dc=us
requesting: All userApplication attributes
```

Any suggestion on how to make the search with the full dn work?. The software I'm trying to integrate with openldap will issue a search with full DN and I have no way to change that.

Thanks!

Comment: You are doing 2 different things with your command. The first searches entries which contain an attribute `cn` which has the value `estebanf`, the second you try to read an entry which you already know the DN (but with the wrong syntax). The correct syntax to read an entry is the one provided by @jwilleke

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
ldapsearch -v -x -H ldap://localhost:389 -b cn=estebanf,ou=People,dc=everteam,dc=us -D "cn=admin,dc=everteam,dc=us" -w everteam  --searchScope base "(objectclass=*)" '*'
```

Which performs a search at the individual user entry requesting all attributes.

-jim